# How should I create an action on the content tab of a folder that acts on all items that are selected?

Tags: action, plone, selecteditem, plone-4.x

I asked a series of questions in a post last week, and the person who answered very wisely suggested that I split it into separate questions.  I have added a CMF action for folders called "Remote Publish".  The button now shows up when viewing the "Content" tab for all folders.  How would one now add the logic to do something as simple as writing the titles of the selected items to a log when the button is clicked?  Ultimately I will have the selected items share their titles with a web service that I have written, but I am thinking baby steps :D  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: But what is doing your action right now?

Comment: Right now there is no action being taken.  I guess that is the real question:  Where do I add the code to carry out the action, and how do I iterate over only content items that are checked(selected) when the user has clicked the button?  Thus far it seems I have only created a stub through-the-web for portal_actions > folder_buttons. I need to know where to put the code for when that button is clicked or learn the whereabouts of a tutorial for custom actions.

Comment: I used 'Change State' CMF Action for a template.  It has a URL expression of 'string:content_status_history:method'.  I located the content_status_history Controller Page Template in portal_skins > plone_forms under the ZMI.  I copied it and used it for my content_remote_publish CPT in portal_skins > custom.  To associate the action for the form with the processing script, do the same with portal_skins > plone_form_scripts to match a Controller Python Script.  To write to the logs, I still have to finish that before I can finish answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is: copy what other button are doing!

For example: copy the CMF skin script name [folder_delete.cpy](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/4fba5b636cc8b64624c69eef7f0e3df5bccd377e/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_scripts/folder_delete.cpy). You'll see that `paths` parameter if loaded from the REQUEST.

Comment: I copied the content_status_modify Controller Python Script to keep with my original approach of copying the content_status_history Controller Page Template, but other than that, I did as you mention.  I removed the workflow code and added actions through ZMI actions tab to refer to the correct script when form buttons are clicked. Iterating over selected items, instead of logging it to plone logs I decided to req.RESPONSE.write(",".join(req.get('paths',[])))